# Upper topology vs. Alexandrov topology

Tags: general-topology, order-theory

Let $(P, \le)$ be a poset. We define the following two well-known topologies over $P$.

The **upper topology** has the principle upper sets, that is upper sets of the form $\{\uparrow x : x \in P\}$, as the subbase.

The **Alexondrov topology** has as base the upper sets, that is sets of the form $\{\uparrow U : \uparrow U \subseteq P\}$.

Now, it is clear that Alexandrov topology is *at least* as big as the upper topology (as every principle upper set is indeed an upper set, while the converse need not hold).

But I have the following confusion.

Since the upper topology will have all  the principle upper sets as open sets, wouldn't then the arbitrary union of these open sets will end up *generating* the whole Alexandrov topology, as every upper set is a union of some set of principle upper sets?

Or, upper topology is simply presented with upper sets and their intersections, and nothing more? I am obviously missing something here.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that your definition of the upper topology is wrong: it’s the topology that has as a subbase all sets of the form $P\,\setminus\!\downarrow\!\!x$ for $x\in P$.

If $\langle X,\tau\rangle$ is a topological space, we can define a preorder order $\le_\tau$ on $X$, called the *specialization order*, by $x\le_\tau y$ if and only if $x\in\operatorname{cl}\{y\}$; $\le_\tau$ is a partial order if $X$ is $T_0$. The upper topology on $P$ is the coarsest topology on $P$ whose specialization order is $\le$, the original order on $P$, and the Alexandrov topology is the finest such topology.

For an example in which the two are distinct, let $P=\Bbb Z\times\Bbb Z$ with the natural product partial order, and let $U=\{\langle m,n\rangle\in P:m\ge -n\}$; clearly $U$ is an upper set and hence open in the Alexandrov topology. Let $p=\langle 0,0\rangle\in U$. If $U$ were open in the upper topology, there would be a finite $F\subseteq P$ such that

$$p\in\bigcap_{x\in F}\left(P\,\setminus\!\downarrow\!\!x\right)\subseteq U\;.$$

Say $F=\{\langle m_k,n_k\rangle:k=1,\ldots,\ell\}$, and let

$$m=\max\{m_k:k=1,\ldots,\ell\}$$

and

$$n=\max\{n_k:k=1,\ldots,\ell\}\;.$$

Then

$$P\,\setminus\!\downarrow\!\!\langle m,n\rangle\subseteq P\setminus\bigcup_{x\in F}\downarrow\!\!x=\bigcap_{x\in F}\left(P\,\setminus\!\downarrow\!\!x\right)\;,$$

but clearly $P\,\setminus\!\downarrow\!\!\langle m,n\rangle\nsubseteq U$, since $P\,\setminus\!\downarrow\!\!\langle m,n\rangle$ contains $\Bbb Z\times\{r\}$ for $r>n$.

Answer (score 2):

Under your definitions, both topologies are the same. Note that the upper sets are non only a base, they form the whole topology. And the principal upper sets are only only a subbase, they from a base.

I have also found another definition of the upper topology: the principal lower sets generate the closed sets. I.e. the open sets has a subbase of form $\{P \setminus \mathop\downarrow x: x ∈ P\}$. This topology may be strictly coarser, but they are the same if the order is linear.

Comment: They are not the same for every linear order. For $ω + 1$ the point $ω$ is isolated in the Alexandrov topology, but not in the upper topology.